# count rows taking into account qty

Tags: mysql

I currently get a count by runningthe following command, and parsing it into a custom `pdo` select function.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo GROUP BY bar`

Table Structure

```
col1 | col2 | bar | qty
------------------------
blahb  blah   abc    1
blahb  blah   abc    3
blahb  blah   abc    1
blahb  blah   aaa    3
blahb  blah   aaa    5
blahb  blah   aaa    1
```

This will return:

`abc => 3 
 aaa => 3`

Is there a way of modifying the query so that the `qty` multiplies the `bar` column?

Desired Result:

`abc => 5 
 aaa => 9`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting the records, use `sum()` to sum up the values

```
select bar, sum(qty)
from foo
group by bar
```